# PHP replace first empty space between two strings (multiple occurrences)

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP I need to replace multiple instances of the first empty space between two strings with another string (in my example a period). I did find several posts with very similar questions, but none seem to help me in this case: I can't seem to catch that first empty space between the **[** and **]** using regex.

```
$replacement = '.';
$str = 'Some string that contains [foo bar more text], then some other text and [foo1 bar1 more text].';
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=\[)\s(?=\])/U', $replacement, $str);
echo $str;
```

which results in

> Some string that contains [foo bar more text], then some other text and [foo1 bar1 more text].

The output I am looking for:

> Some string that contains [foo.bar more text], then some other text and [foo1.bar1 more text].

Maybe the complete approach is wrong? Please point me in the right direction, if possible with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont' need the lookarounds. You can match `[` followed by any char except `[` and `]` or a whitespace char.

Use `\K` to clear the match buffer and match a horizontal whitespace char `\h`, or use `\s` to match a whitespace char which can also match a newline.

If you want to match 1 or more occurrences, you can use a quantifier using a plus `\h+`

```
\[[^][\s]*\K\h
```

In the replacement use a dot.

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f79oZs/1)

---

As @[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) points out, you can assert the closing `]` using a positive lookahead `(?=[^][]*])`

The more precise pattern would be

```
\[[^][\s]*\K\h(?=[^][]*])
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `[^][\s]*` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 0+ times any char except `[` `]` or a whitspace char *(Use `+` instead of `*` if there has to be a minimum of 1 char following the opening `[`)*
- `\K\h` Clear the match buffer and match a horizontal whitespace char
- `(?=[^][]*])` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is a closing `]` again using the negated character class.

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFfcHe/1) or a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/9bl3u)

**Example code**

```
$replacement = '.';
$str = 'Some string that contains [foo bar more text], then some other text and [foo1 bar1 more text].';
$str = preg_replace('/\[[^][\s]*\K\h(?=[^][]*])/', $replacement, $str);
echo $str;
```

**Output**

> Some string that contains [foo.bar more text], then some other text
> and [foo1.bar1 more text].

Comment: To make sure the whitespace is actually between `[...]`, `\[[^][\s]*\K\s+(?=[^][]*])` would be a bit more precise

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ow yes, true

Comment: Thanks to both of you! And yes, I have to make sure the whitespace is actually between `[...]`. I have spent so much time on this, the Explanation about Negated character class is the key for my understanding.